# Spin structures on schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, schemes

This is a very naive question, but I have been wondering about the role of spin geometry and spinor structures in the context of algebraic geometry. I know the definition of spin structures and associated spinor bundles on manifolds and CW-complexes. The question is: is there analog notions of the following classical objects:

- Spin structure
- Bundle of Clifford algebras
- Spinor bundle/bundle of Clifford modules

in the context of schemes (over the complex numbers) and which can be developed in a purely algebraic language? For example, is there a notion of "spin structure" or sheaf of Clifford algebras on a scheme?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that part of the problem is that defining a Spin structure requires a nondegenerate quadratic form on your bundle. In topology you can always choose a positive definite one (they're all equivalent anyway) but over a scheme the question is much more subtle

Comment: If I remember correctly (it's been a while) the usual condition for existence is of a spin structure on a manifold is for $w_2=0$. So for a complex manifold, it would be enough to know that $c_1$ is even, or that the canoncal bundle has a square root. These are classically called theta characteristics. This is probably different from what you are after, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @DonuArapura: I am precisely interested in the situation on schemes, not on manifold or complex manifolds, which is well-known.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider holomorphic spin structures on complex algebraic manifolds. If you try to reduce the frame bundle of a complex manifold to a holomorphic spin structure, you will induce a reduction to a holomorphic Riemannian metric, giving a holomorphic affine connection, forcing the vanishing of the Atiyah class, and therefore the vanishing of all Chern classes. Therefore the manifold admits a finite unramified covering by a complex torus, and the holomorphic Riemannian metric is translation invariant. So you don't want a holomorphic spin structure, unless you want to allow singularities.

Comment: I am precisely interested in the case where there are singularities. In particular I would like to know if there is a reasonable intrinsic definition of spin structure or spinor bundle on a scheme. Intrinsic in the sense that it can be defined in algebraic terms and without any reference to any underlying smooth manifold, which may not exist.